# Unstable set official abbreviation

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-joke-cards

Unstable release is being listed as UST in

- magiccards.info https://magiccards.info/ust/en.html
- wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_sets

Yet we see it having hashtag #MTGUN3 at official product page https://magic.wizards.com/en/products/unstable

Will it be UST or UN3 eventually?

Comment: Official in what context? The magiccards.info site says "This website is not produced, endorsed, supported, or affiliated with Wizards of the Coast." And if you follow [the citations on Wikipedia](https://i.imgur.com/jDmHR66.png), you'll find that one of the citations is a broken link, and the other leads to the main Gatherer page.

Comment: magic.wizards.com is the official product page of Magic. magiccards.info and wikipedia are not.

Comment: I'd take what's printed on the card over what's on any website (save gatherer for oracle text, not really an issue here) and the cards do now have the abbreviation on them by the collectors number, it's UST.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The set code is **UST**. It's already official, and you can see it printed on the bottom left of your card, in this case on [Adorable Kitten](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAdorable%20Kitten%5d):

[image: set code in the bottom left of Adorable Kitten: UST.]

The set code is always present there.

The hashtag may be #MTGUN3, but it's still UST for a set code.

Answer (score 7):

**The Official set code is UST, and can be found in the bottom left corner of all [cards from the set](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439390).**

As for why some tweets from Official sources use the #MTGUN3, #MTGUN3 was already a popular hashtag and wizard's did not want to split the marketing effort between two hashtags.

This question was actually covered on [Mark Rosewater's Blog](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/168733494158/why-was-the-hashtag-for-unstable-mtgun3-when-the):

> **howdidigethereimnotgoodwithmagic asked: Why was the Hashtag for Unstable #MTGUN3 when the set code on the cards is UST?**
>
> **MR:** Because we didn’t want half the people using #mtgust and half using #mtgun3. In other words, we went with the flow.